# How to convert a curl Plaid request to swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, curl, plaid

Im trying to use the Plaid API in swift, but it seems that they have no way of natively making API requests in swift, however they do have curl. I know that you can make curl API requests in swift.

The docs show this API request in curl

```
curl -X POST https://sandbox.plaid.com/link/token/create -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{
  "client_id": "CLIENT_ID",
  "secret": "SECRET",
  "user": {    "client_user_id": "unique-per-user",
  },
  "client_name": "Plaid App",
  "products": ["auth"],
  "country_codes": ["GB"],
  "language": "en",
  "webhook": "https://sample-web-hook.com",
  "account_filters": {
      "depository": {
          "account_subtypes": ["checking"]
      }
  }
}'
```

How would I translate this curl request to swift - specifically in swiftUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That’s a pretty specific question, and to some degree no one can answer it for you. You’ll have to write the code yourself to be able to understand and debug it when things go wrong.  That being said, here’s a pretty good tutorial on how to make http post requests:

https://www.appsdeveloperblog.com/http-post-request-example-in-swift/

The relevant section starts like:

```
// Prepare URL 
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
// Prepare URL Request Object
var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// HTTP Request Parameters which will be sent in HTTP Request Body 
let postString = "userId=300&title=My urgent task&completed=false";
```

Obviously you’ll want to use the plaid variables instead of the example. But that should get you started.